# android NDK : cannot find execution point

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, lldb

I'm debugging my Android app in Android Studio, and it failed to find execution point of native code, as a result, variables also cannot be shown:
[image: img1]
`World::flush` looks like this:

```
void World::flush() {
    LOGE_LS("Flushing cached chunks...");
    for (chunk_lru_li *i = lru, *j; i != nullptr; i = j) {
        if (i->item->flag == CHUNK_LI_DIRTY) {
            LOGE_LS("Saving chunk (%d,%d).", i->item->key.x_div16, i->item->key.z_div16);
            i->item->val->save();
            LOGE_LS("Saved chunk.");
        }
        j = i->next;
        delete i->item->val;
        delete i->item;
        delete i;
    }
    lru = nullptr;
    mru = nullptr;
    num_chunks = 0;
    memset(chunks, 0, sizeof(chunks));
    LOGE_LS("Flusing done.");
}
```

1. Debugger type was set to `Native`.
2. Threads and call stack are displayed.
3. This used to work several months ago within the same project.
4. Release version of a shared library was used but does not seems to be the reason.
5. I tried many variables of different functions in the call stack, not only the `lru` in screenshot.
6. Build variants of all modules are `debug` (Otherwise the app won't be debuggable at all)

Thanks meow~

Answer (score 0):

Solved by searching on CSDN blog:

1. Find your module that contains c/c++ code, open its `iml` file on the `Project` panel:
   [image]
2. find this tag: `<facet type="native-android-gradle" name="Native-Android-Gradle">`
   [image]
3. under the tag find `<option name="SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT" value="release" />`
4. change `release` to `debug`. If it's already `debug` then it seems **not** the reason to **your** problem.
5. Save & Close the file then do Gradle sync.
6. It should be fixed now. If not, clean build may or may not help.

Link of original answer at CSDN blog: https://blog.csdn.net/wangyun522/article/details/78820569
It's **not in English** and you may not want to check it out.